# How to Insert Multiple Arrays into the Same MySQL Database Without One Array Overriding the next?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have a set of functions on my class.post.php page that insert arrays into MySQL relationship table tbl_posts_prop, which is suppose to store the ids of the post (post_id), the client that initiated the post (user_id), the array of client(s) that are selected whom profile page the post should be fed to (type_id) as well as the array of category(ies) that are chosen for the post to be filtered by (prop_id), and the array of file(s) uploaded (file_id) via the jquery file uploader along with the file(s) type (type) if any are attached with the post.

The issue I'm having is the $prop_id (array of the category(ies) selected from the Category $post_cat field) overrides the $type_id (array of of the client(s) selected from the Clients $userids field) when the data stored in the relationship table tbl_posts_prop if the prop_id array is called first before the type_id array and vice vera.

If I call the prop_id by itself it stores the selected category(ies) id(s) from the post_cat field properly as well as stores the selected client(s) id(s) from the userids field if I call the type_id by itself. However, it doesn't store the both if I call the two arrays at the same time. The user_id and post_id stores in the table properly as well. The file id and type from the files SQL table currently doesn't store to the tbl_posts_prop, but I am trying to sort out the issue a step at a time as I'm not an expert in coding I am just trying to finish my site as soon as possible with the limited resources I have that I can have it launched.

[this is the frontend of my post form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM4FY.jpg)
[this is my tbl_posts_prop table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNAJc.png)

The current code I have is:
(my class.post.php code)

```html
<?php

 include_once('class.database.php');

 class Post extends Database {
  private $sql = NULL;
  public $retval  = array();
  private $tblname = 'tbl_posts';
  private $tblname1 = 'tbl_music_properties';
  private $tblname2 = 'tbl_music_artists';  
  private $tblname3 = 'tbl_posts_prop';
  private $tblname4 = 'files';
  
  public function getClientsForSelect($id){
   $selectedProp = $this->getSelectedProperties($id);
   $preselected  = array();
   if($selectedProp){
    foreach ($selectedProp as $key => $value) {
     $preselected[] = $value['type_id'];
    }
   }
   $option = '';
   $this->sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tblname2;
   $this->data = $this->fetch_rows_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data)){
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
     $selected = in_array($value['id'], $preselected) ? 'selected' : '';
     $option .= "<option value='{$value['id']}' {$selected}>{$value['aname']}</option>";
    }
   }
   return $option;
  }

  public function getCategoriesForSelect($field, $id){
   $selectedProp = $this->getSelectedProperties($id, 'artist');
   $preselected  = array();
   if($selectedProp){
    foreach ($selectedProp as $key => $value) {
     $preselected[] = $value['prop_id'];
    }
   }
   $option = '';
   $this->sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tblname1 . ' WHERE mp_type = "'.$field.'"';
   $this->data = $this->fetch_rows_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data)){
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
     $selected = in_array($value['mp_id'], $preselected) ? 'selected' : ''; 
     $option .= "<option value='{$value['mp_id']}' {$selected}>{$value['mp_name']}</option>";
    }
   }
   return $option;
  }
    
  public function add_prop($arr, $post_id, $user_id){
   $retval['type'] = $type;
   $retval['post_id'] = $post_id;
   $retval['user_id'] = $user_id;
   $retval['file_id'] = $file_id;
   foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $retval['prop_id'] = $value;
    $retval['type_id'] = $value;
    $this->insert($retval, $this->tblname3);
   }
  }
  
  public function getSelectedProperties($id, $type){
   $this->sql  = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tblname3 . ' WHERE type = "' . $type . '" AND type_id = ' . $id;
   $this->data = $this->fetch_rows_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data))
    return $this->data; 
   else{
    return false; 
   }  
  }
```

(post_form code)

```html
<?php

 include('includes/inc.php');
 include("includes/classes/class.post.php");
 $post  = new Post();
 
 //new 
 $data['formStatus'] = 'new';
 $data['post_id'] = 0;
 $data['id'] = 0;
 $data['aid'] = 0;
 $data['caid'] = 0;
 $data['gid'] = 0;
 $data['fid'] = 0;

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
  $post_id  = isset($_GET['post_id']) ? $_GET['post_id'] : 0;

  $checkRow = $post->get_row($post_id);
  if(is_array($checkRow)){
   $data['formStatus'] = 'edit';
   $data['row'] = $checkRow;
   $data['id'] = $checkRow['id'];
   $data['post_id'] = $checkRow['post_id'];
   $data['fid'] = $checkRow['id'];
   $data['aid'] = $checkRow['id'];
   $data['post'] = checkImagexists('../../uploads/', 'post_' . $checkRow['post_id']);
  }
 }
 
 $data['clients']  = $post->getClientsForSelect('artist', $data['aid']);
 $data['postcat'] = $post->getCategoriesForSelect('category', $data['id']);
 $data['postgenre']   = $post->getCategoriesForSelect('genre', $data['id']);
 $data['postfield']   = $post->getCategoriesForSelect('field', $data['id']);
 layout('post_form', $data);
?>
```

(postcontroller.php code)

```html
<?php

 session_start();

 include("includes/functions.php");
 include("includes/classes/class.post.php"); 
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
  $post_cat = isset($_POST['post_cat']) ? $_POST['post_cat'] : array();

  $files = $_POST['files'];
  
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];    
  $userids = isset($_POST['userids']) ? $_POST['userids'] : array(); 
  $file_id = isset($_POST['file_id']) ? $_POST['file_id'] : array();
  $type = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : array(); 

  /*echo "<pre>";
  print_r($post_cat);
  print_r($userids);
  print_r($_POST);
  print_r($_FILES); exit;*/                
  
  $post = new post();
  $arrData = array();
  
  $arrData['name'] = addslashes(ucwords($_POST['name']));
  $arrData['details'] = addslashes($_POST['details']);
  $arrData['post_link'] = $_POST['post_link'];  
  $arrData['status'] = addslashes($_POST['status']);
  $arrData['category'] = addslashes($_POST['category']);
   
  if(empty($_POST['post_id'])){
   $arrData['user_id'] = $user_id;
   $arrData['added_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
   $insert = $post->add($arrData);
   if($insert){
                                $post->add_prop($post_cat, $insert, $user_id);    
    if(!empty($files)){
    //Rename all files in the upload server php directory to post_id format
    //Move files to upload directory
    foreach ($files as $file){  
     if ($handle = opendir('../../uploads/client/files/')) {
      while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
       $newName = '../../uploads/' . 'post_' . $_POST['id'] . '_' . $file;
       $oldName = '../../uploads/client/files/' . $file;
       rename($oldName, $newName);
      }
     }
     closedir($handle);
    }
    
   }
  }  
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Invalid file";
                }   
 }

 header('Location: post.php?act=' . $_SESSION['insert_post']);
?>
```

(post_form connection code)

```html
    <form id="postForm" action="postcontroller.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">     
     <!-- start id-form -->
     <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="id-form">
     <tr>
      <th valign="top">Post Title:</th>
      <td><input type="text" class="inp-form required" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($data['row']['name'])) echo $data['row']['name']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th valign="top">Description:</th>
      <td><textarea class="form-textarea" cols="" rows="" name="details"><?php if(isset($data['row']['details'])) echo $data['row']['details']; ?></textarea></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th valign="top">URL:</th>
      <td><input type="url" class="inp-form" name="post_link" value="<?php if(isset($data['row']['post_link'])) echo $data['row']['post_link']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>     
      <th valign="top">Client:</th>
      <td>      
       <select name="userids[]" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Client..." style="width:350px;" multiple>
      <?php echo $data['clients']; ?>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th valign="top">Category:</th>
      <td>
       <select name="post_cat[]" class="chosen-select required" data-placeholder="Choose a Category..." style="width:350px;" multiple>
        <?php echo $data['postcat']; ?>
        <?php echo $data['postgenre']; ?>
        <?php echo $data['postfield']; ?>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th valign="top">Status:</th>
      <td>
       <select class="chosen-select" name="status">
        <option value="1" <?php if(isset($data['row']['status']) && $data['row']['status'] == '1') echo "selected";  ?>>Active</option>
        <option value="0" <?php if(isset($data['row']['status']) && $data['row']['status'] == '0') echo "selected";  ?>>Inactive</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
       <input type="submit" value="" class="form-submit" />
       <input id="restform" class="form-reset">
       <a href="post.php" class="form-cancel">Cancel</a>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <input type="hidden" name="form" value="<?php echo $data['formStatus'] ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $data['post_id'] ?>" />
    </form>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: How do you think someone read all this code and comment .? . please provide only the minimal code and description for get the point  ..

Comment: Hello, @scaisEdge I'm afraid this is the minimal code as I've removed every other part of the code that isn't related to the issue. The main issue is that when I try to insert both arrays in the code one overrides the other as you can see in the screenshot of my sql table. I would like assistance in resolving this.

Comment: @scaisEdge I hope I did you proud and trimmed down everything enough for you without losing the focal point of the issue in my post. If not feel free to kindly make suggestions of what else can be removed.

Comment: My was only a suggestion .. normally when some coder see this question is not really involved to evaluete .. but for me now it's only too late .. in my country is deep night and is saturday .. so i thnik of looking at this  question in a secondt  moment  ..